# Magento 2: Cannot open the Product Detail Page

Tags: magento2.3, category, review, product-page, listing

I'm trying to open the product detail page from the listing page but its not working, and its showing the below error:

```
2 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Invalid block type: Magento\Review\Block\Product\Review
Exception #1 (ReflectionException): Class Magento\Review\Block\Product\Review does not exist
```

Can anyone please help me to rectify this error?

When I try to open the product page, its not opening and I can see the below error in view-source:

```
<meta property="og:type" content="product" />
<meta property="og:title" content="<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getName() on null in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/opengraph/general.phtml:13
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php.php(59): include()
#1 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(271): Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php-&gt;render(Object(vendor\module\Block\Index\Index), '/var/www/html/v...', Array)
#2 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(301): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template-&gt;fetchView('/var/www/html/v...')
#3 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(1094): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template-&gt;_toHtml()
#4 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(1098): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock-&gt;Magento\Framework\View\Element\{closure}()
#5 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(671): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Abst in <b>/var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/opengraph/general.phtml</b> on line <b>13</b><br />
```

Comment: did you check the logs/report?

Answer (score 0):

try to run the command to re generate class

> sudo php bin/magento setup:di:compile

Comment: I have done that but still its showing the error

Answer (score 0):

Check the constructor.  Problem is with the Constructor params . After fixing it run di:compile

Answer (score 0):

Check Whether `Magento\Review\Block\Product\Review` is overridden. If so, then cross check the block extends type.

Also, check the `catalog_product_view.xml` file whether the review block class is mentioned correctly as

`<block class="Magento\Review\Block\Product\Review" name="reviews.tab" as="reviews" template="Magento_Review::review.phtml" group="detailed_info" ifconfig="catalog/review/active">`

If everything is correctly, Please follow below steps

1) rm -rf var/* pub/static/* generated/* (to remove all cache, static content and generated files)

2) php bin/magento setup:upgrade && php bin/magento setup:di:compile && php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

Note: Use **-f** if you are in developer mode.

Comment: I have updated the question, please check @Sathishkumar

Comment: @Siva, I noticed the product name itself not getting and throwing an error. Have you done any migration of DB. Also, check the admin panel whether the product is available. If so, try to edit and save it.